# Facebook extended permissions and interested_in property

Tags: iphone, facebook, permissions, ios

Which Facebook extended permissions makes the interested_in property of friends show up?

I've tried using friends_about_me, friends_relationship_details, and friends_relationships.

Which one is interested_in located? I'm using the Facebook SDK for iOS devices by the way.

If not enough are found, is it because I'm doing something wrong or is it the individual users' settings are set up that way? On the Facebook profile page it might show Interested In: Women while the Graph API query might not show it even with the above extended permissions granted.

Also when I try it with a query string ID?fields=interested_in, I get nulls, except for a couple.

Comment: Have you tried interests? - "user_interests      friends_interests      Provides access to the user's list of interests as the interests connection"

Comment: yes I have. also gender doesn't appear for some people. strange

Comment: You probably should take down all those user Ids from this question. That is clearly a violation of Facebook TOS.

Comment: Facebook does not force you to supply a gender, so some users gender may be blank. It also seems that strict privacy preferences by the user effect the data visible in OpenGraph, but I have not verified this thoroughly.

Comment: Actually I figured out the gender part. I was querying the wrong thing. I queried ID/interested_in and trying to extract gender. I should've just queried ID. The gender works now at least.

Answer (score 5):

The permission is "friends_relationship_details". The query you are showing above is actually correct. The one thing you are forgetting is that ultimately each use can set what data their friends can share about them. The default settings for which information friends can share does NOT allow friends to grant an application access to "interested in and looking for" and "religions and political views". So in short, your query is correct and you are getting all the information you are allowed to access.

Most Facebook users have not changed these settings, meaning that only the users that have explicitly allowed friends to share interested in information will show up in your query. This will be almost nobody which is why you only have one result in your query.

To see what I am talking about go to: http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy, click the "Edit your settings for using applications, games and websites." link, then click "Edit Settings" in the "Info accessible through your friends" section. Here you will see what permissions you allow your friends to share. There is no override for this. If you don't want the information shared, your friends can't force you to share it.

Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: There is no workaround. You cannot force somebody to share information they don't want to share. If you want to get that information from friends then you have to have the user invite their friend to use your app and then ask the user for permission to read that data.

Comment: There is no permission for gender. If a user has checked the "Show my sex in my profile" box then their gender is public. If they have not checked that box then their gender is always private. In my experience about half of users will have their gender set to public. Meaning you can get the gender of about half of a user's friends.